# How to insert strings in Array? Using BASH script

Tags: arrays, bash

Here is the text in myText.txt:

```
   a    d
   b    e
   c    f
```

`a` and `d` are separated with `\t` and each row are separated with `\n`. I would like to insert these in an two arrays.

This must be the content:

```
  arr1=(a b c)
  arr2=(d e f)
```

Code done so far:

```
  c1=`cat $2 | cut -f1`
  c2=`cat $2 | cut -f2`
```

But I don't know how to place these values in the array/s.

Comment: The order should be retained?

Comment: Can you let us know if the problem was solved with the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets built the variable first:

```
a=$'a\td\nb\te\nc\tf'
echo "$a"
#Output
a       d
b       e
c       f
```

Split to arrays with pure bash:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r var1 var2; do
arr1+=("$var1")
arr2+=("$var2")
done <<<"$a"
declare -p arr1 arr2
#Output
declare -a arr1='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'                                                                                                                                     
declare -a arr2='([0]="d" [1]="e" [2]="f")'
```

Split to arrays with bash and awk , without loop:

```
arr1=($(awk -F'\t' '{print $1}' <<<"$a"))
arr2=($(awk -F'\t' '{print $2}' <<<"$a"))
#Output as before
```

Comment: @John Thanks - I have also post a bash solution with kind of 2d arrays in your other question.